# Implementing interface in java

Tags: java, oop, interface

I'm developing a java program and my problem is that I want to write a general method for calling a
        specific method on a few classes, and the class is not known.

for example in normal use i write this piece of code for RootLayoutController class and it works:

```
RootLayoutController controller = loader.getController();
        controller.setMainApp(this)
```

but the problem is that i have to write a lot of methods to call them!
so i created PageController interface ( with setMainApp() inside ) and implemented it in  RootLayoutController and other classes ; then changed the method to this:

```
Object controller = loader.getController();
        ((PageController) controller).setMainApp(this);
```

but it throws classcastexception and I don't know much about interface so I can't debug it!
thanks so much

Comment: Why are you getting back an object when you know you need something that implements the `PageController` interface?

Comment: It's pretty clear that `loader.getController()` is not returning a `PageController`. But you haven't told us what it *does* return, so I can't say any more than that.

Comment: it returns a class , it may be RootLayoutController or something else like PersonOverviewController!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under java 8, file PageController.java (interface):

```
package test;

@FunctionalInterface
public interface PageController {
    void setMainApp(PageController c);
}
```

File PageControllerImpl.java (test implementation):

```
package test;

public class PageControllerImpl implements PageController {

    @Override
    public void setMainApp(PageController c) {
        // TODO your implemenrtation

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PageController testController = new PageControllerImpl();
        testController.setMainApp(testController);        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have an interface `PageController`, you can do (because a `RootLayoutController` is a `PageController`.):

```
PageController controller = loader.getController();
```

and then, there is no necessity to cast:

```
controller.setMainApp(this);
```

This is why interfaces exist.

Comment: That is, if `getController` isn't actually returning `Object`.

Comment: that works! thank you so much, I knew I had to use interface because all of those classes are doing the same action but I didn't know much about the syntax!